# Reverse Vlookup

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, vlookup

Trying to get the last associated DATE with an ID (There are multiple entries for each ID)

Table structure is as follows;

[image]

i.e - I need to vlookup by ID No:5, and have the last date returned = 12/5/2019

Any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) be useful for you?

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
=index(B2:B,large(row(B2:B)*(A2:A=5),1))
```

or..

```
=+sort(B2:B,row(A2:A)*(A2:A = 5),)
```

Change range to suit.

Note: depending on your locale, you may have to change the comma's in the formulas to semi-colons.